# how can i get us all state in magento?

Tags: magento

```
   <li class="state">
        <label for="State" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select id="State" name="State" title="<?php echo $this->__('State') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
             </select>

             <input type="text" id="State" name="State" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
       </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: please improve your question, it's unclear and not well formated

Comment: i want to show all state list  in drop down in my extension  my code is @adrien54

Answer (score 2):

You can use get the list of states as:

**Code**

```html
 <li class="state">
        <label for="State" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select id="State" name="State" title="<?php echo $this->__('State') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
               <?php 
                $regionCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()
                                    //->addCountryFilter()
                                    ->load();
                foreach($regionCollection as $region){
                  echo "<option value=$region[name]>".$region['name'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
             </select>

             <input type="text" id="State" name="State" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
       </div>
  </li>
```

Note: this code comment: **//->addCountryFilter()** can be uncommented if you want to filter by specific country e.g 'US' or 'CA' or 'FR' etc

Comment: @ArvindJha feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use directory API instead of resource collection:

```
Mage::getModel('directory/region_api')->items('US')
```